# how to make style change shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I reduce this part code? I need to make it shorter.

Here's my really long part of code:

```
var b1 = document.getElementById("b1");
var b2 = document.getElementById("b2");

b1.onclick = function() {
  b1.style.background = "#0070b7";
  b1.style.color = "#fff";
  b2.style.background = "";
  b2.style.color = "";
  b3.style.background = "";
  b3.style.color = "";
  b4.style.background = "";
  b4.style.color = "";
  $( "#led1" ).show( "slow, linear" );
  $( "#led2" ).hide("slow, linear");
}

b2.onclick = function() {
  b1.style.background = "#efefef";
  b1.style.color = "#707173";
  b2.style.background = "#0070b7";
  b2.style.color = "#fff";
  b3.style.background = "";
  b3.style.color = "";
  b4.style.background = "";
  b4.style.color = "";
  $( "#led1" ).hide("slow, linear ");
  $( "#led2" ).show( "slow, linear " );
}
```

Comment: Just a side note, [Code Review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is probably more appropriate for this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

The biggest optimization I can see would be to use CSS classes instead of manually setting the style for every element in javascript. For instance:

```
.active {
   background-color: #efefef;
   color: #707173;
}

.inactive {
   background-color: #fff;
   color: #fff;
}
```

Then your click event handlers can just do:

```
$('.active').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
```

or something similar to that

Answer (score 1):

I've made it somewhat shorter (and more complete, and more readable) by using Jquery's `.css()` function instead of the plain JS `element.style.attribute` syntax. Also defined each variable once at the top to prevent the need to re-query. Here's my try:

```
var b1 = $('#b1');
var b2 = $('#b2');
var b3 = $('#b3');
var b4 = $('#b4');
var led1 = $('#led1');
var led2 = $('#led2');

b1.click(function(){
  b1.css({ background: '#0070b7', color: '#fff' });
  b2.css({ background: '', color: '' });
  b3.css({ background: '', color: '' });
  b4.css({ background: '', color: '' });
  led1.show('slow, linear');
  led2.hide('slow, linear');
});

b2.click(function(){
  b1.css({ background: '#efefef', color: '#707173' });
  b2.css({ background: '#0070b7', color: '#fff' });
  b3.css({ background: '', color: '' });
  b4.css({ background: '', color: '' });
  led1.hide('slow, linear');
  led2.show('slow, linear');
});
```

You could definitely get it shorter than this, but there's a point of "diminishing returns" where the space you save is paid for by increasingly complex, hard-to-read, and/or inefficient code.